# How to get group-by result and individual rows from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently I have a table like this:

| Partno | Total |
| --- | --- |
| 0100 | 50 |
| 0100 | 200 |
| 0100 | 300 |
| 0450 | 100 |
| 0450 | 350 |
| 0600 | 250 |

I'd like to get a result like this:

| Partno | Total |
| --- | --- |
| *0100* | *550* |
| 0100 | 50 |
| 0100 | 200 |
| 0100 | 300 |
| *0450* | *450* |
| 0450 | 100 |
| 0450 | 350 |
| *0600* | *250* |
| 0600 | 250 |

Where the italic rows are grouped-by on Partno. How can I get this result using a query?

Right now I have to do it using a master-detail grid, because I can't fit it in 1 query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will retrieves all rows from the table and also includes additional rows that represent the sum of Total values for each unique Partno :

```
SELECT Partno, Total
FROM mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT Partno, SUM(Total)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY Partno
ORDER BY Partno, Total DESC
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/nrWP45Od)

Comment: I strongly suggest not using `SELECT *` especially when UNION/UNION ALL is included

Comment: @ErgestBasha iw ould decline that, it is a bad habit to write a SELECT * with mo9re than two or three this gets rapidly unclear

Comment: @nbk Can you explain why it would not be bad when you have less then 4

Comment: i come across multiple students that try to union and ask why theey get an error,  and i explain them to try to write the columnames and align them to see if all columns fit  the wanted result. with only a few it is easy when you more and more most can handle that any more and lose sight

Comment: @nbk Than IMHO you have not given a good reason why it is not a bad habit when you only have a few columns. You should learn them to do it correct even if its just a few... After all, that is where bad habbits come from. If you allow them to do it with just a few, they picked up a bad habbit

Comment: Worth noting this will result in 2 scans of the table, as opposed to 1. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DUeQ4Al8)

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you need to use `GROUPING SETS` here. Note that if you have 2 or more rows with the *same* value of `Total` they will be aggregated; if that's the case you should be using your primary key column instead (which is omitted in the sample data):

```sql
SELECT Partno,
       SUM(Total) AS Total
FROM (VALUES('0100',50),
            ('0100',200),
            ('0100',300),
            ('0450',100),
            ('0450',350),
            ('0600',250))V(Partno,Total)
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS((PartNo,Total),
                       (PartNo))
ORDER BY V.Partno,
         V.Total;
```

Comment: this still doesn' return the wanted result

Comment: This is working only if  (Partno, Total) are unique : https://dbfiddle.uk/-f_fcvby

Comment: @SelVazi that is *explicitly* denoted in the answer and an answer suggested. To repeat myself, however: "Note that if you have 2 or more rows with the _same_ value of `Total` they will be aggregated; if that's the case you should be using your primary key column instead"

Comment: For the sample data provided, @nbk, this returned exactly what the OP is after: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2uu674aU).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by using UNION ALL between two queries:

```
select partno,total,1 as sort_col 
 from my_table

union all 

select partno,sum(total) total,0  
 from my_table group by partno

order by partno,sort_col
```